# How do I use Python to implement a circular task that executes every 100ms

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I needed to simulate two scenarios in which a piece of data would be inserted into the Redis database every `100ms` using `redis.xadd("stream_name", {"key": "value"}, maxlen=100, approximate=False)` which is the function of the `Redis-Stream` data type. I want to keep the insertion `timestamp` of the Redis database the same in both scenarios

Therefore, I also need to set the same `start time`, so that at the same start time and `the same loop interval` which is `100ms`, the insertion time which is used xadd function of two Redis data should be consistent.

I looked up and found that the `Apscheduler` was a good timing task, but its interval was only up to `seconds`, not `milliseconds`.

I don't know what better way to implement my scenario requirements.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if this will satisfy your requirements but the `time.sleep()` function can do milliseconds via decimal argument.

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    sleep(0.1)  # or 100/1000
    # do something
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but to ensure that the work code is run roughly every 100ms, it should be run in a thread. Otherwise the time the work code needs is added and the next run is in 100ms + the time the work code needs

Comment: You're right @JürgenBayer there should be an overhead.

Comment: `time.sleep` is an easy way to do it, but is it accurate enough?
And I want to be able to define the start time, which doesn't seem to work at `time.sleep`

Comment: I say it is accurate enough. You may create an initial while loop to check if it is the time to start. If "super-accuracy" down to micro/nanosecond is your goal, better to use a compiled language like C on Unix-like system (not Windows because Windows is not a real-time OS).